# Move function support managed data type in Delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, append, delphi-7

I'm trying to implement array append in Delphi 7, because the standard library does not have it. So, the closest answer I can found: [array append in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435314/array-append-in-delphi). But it does not support managed types but I want to implement managed array append. I find the Move function from the answer is the main problem.

Does there exist algorithm to act like Move function and support managed array?
Thanks.

Comment: As David said: "it is certainly possible to replicate what the compiler does when assigning a managed type. But is it really worthwhile?"

Comment: Use SetLength and a for loop to assign the items